# Java, object.hashCode(values change 9 and 10 figits)

Tags: java, hashcode

Result at OUT :

```
1956725890
356573597
1735600054
21685669
2133927002
```

Code:

```
public class Nemchinskiy {
    int date;
    String surname;


    Nemchinskiy(int n, String s) {

        date = n;
        surname = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nemchinskiy chelovek1 = new Nemchinskiy(30, "Roma");
        Nemchinskiy chelovek2 = new Nemchinskiy(30, "Roma");
        Nemchinskiy chelovek3 = new Nemchinskiy(30, "Roma");
        Nemchinskiy chelovek4 = new Nemchinskiy(30, "Roma");
        Nemchinskiy chelovek5 = new Nemchinskiy(30, "Roma");

        int hCode;
        hCode = chelovek1.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hCode);
        hCode = chelovek2.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hCode);
        hCode = chelovek3.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hCode);
        hCode = chelovek4.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hCode);
        hCode = chelovek5.hashCode();
        System.out.println(hCode);
    }}
```

Question: Why it is or 10 or 9 digits?  and every second is 9 strongly)(

Comment: Question: Why not?

Comment: on what it depends? if my Object values are same...

Comment: **These objects are equivalent but not the same**. There is at least one think different, the reference or adress in memory. You can check simply with `chelovek1 == checlovek2` to see that there are not the same.

Comment: Read and understand the javadoc for Object#hashCode: Unless you provide an own implementation it "typically" defaults to "converting the internal address of the object into an integer" and since you have different objects, these addresses will be different as well.

Comment: Every call to new instantiates a new object.  If you don't override equals and hashCode, as you should, the default behavior is from java.lang.Object.

Comment: The default hashCode() is a randomly generated 31-bit number for each individual object regardless of what the object contains. If you want to do something else you need to override the method. it can be 1 to 10 digits long.

Comment: FWIW, output on my computer: `1829164700
2018699554
1311053135
118352462
1550089733`. Four out of five are 10 digits. So this varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will override the hashcode , then hashcode will be generated using that hashcode method, otherwise Object class's hashcode method will be used, and it generate hashcode according to the address/reference of object in jvm.

There is equal and hashcode  relation as well [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074996/hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java-object---a-pragmatic-concept.html)

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

**hashCode()** returns gets the memory address of the object reference and converts it into integer format by using some logic. So the outcome of **hashCode()** will depend on the memory also.

These are my cases

> Case : 1

```
public class HashCode9And10 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HashCode9And10 h1 = new HashCode9And10();
        HashCode9And10 h2 = new HashCode9And10();
        HashCode9And10 h3 = new HashCode9And10();
        HashCode9And10 h4 = new HashCode9And10();
        HashCode9And10 h5 = new HashCode9And10();
        HashCode9And10 h6 = new HashCode9And10();

        System.out.println(h1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h2.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h3.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h4.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h5.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h6.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Output

```
4072869
1671711
11394033
4384790
9634993
1641745
```

See among the six hashcodes only one is 8-digit, others are 7-digit

> Case : 2

```
public class HashCode9And10 
{
    int i;
    String s;

    public HashCode9And10(int i, String s) 
    {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HashCode9And10 h1 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");
        HashCode9And10 h2 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");
        HashCode9And10 h3 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");
        HashCode9And10 h4 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");
        HashCode9And10 h5 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");
        HashCode9And10 h6 = new HashCode9And10(1, "asd");

        System.out.println(h1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h2.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h3.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h4.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h5.hashCode());
        System.out.println(h6.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Output

```
4072869
1671711
11394033
4384790
9634993
1641745
```

Here also output pattern is same and not 10 and 9 digits. So there will be difference, the number of digits will vary.